# Using if not exists to insert data from tableA to tableB and return insert ID from tableB

Tags: python, mysql

So I'm working on this database structuring and trying to figure out if this is the best method. I'm pulling records from a 3rd party site and store them to a temporary table (tableA) I then check for duplicates in tableB and then insert the non duplicated in to tableB from tableA. Is there anyway to get the id assigned from tableB each time a record is inserted? Right now I'm looking for the latest records inserted in tableB by date and then retrieving the IDs. Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you're not using `INSERT IGNORE`? It seems to me that you could do away with the whole temporary-table process...

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
|----|------|
|  1 | adam |
|  2 |  bob |
|  3 | carl |
+----+------+
```

If `id` has a unique constraint, then this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tableName (id, name) VALUES (3, "carl"), (4, "dave");
```

...will result in:

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
|----|------|
|  1 | adam |
|  2 |  bob |
|  3 | carl |
|  4 | dave |
+----+------+
```

...whereas if you'd just done an `INSERT` (without the `IGNORE` part), it would give you a unique key constraint error.

In terms of getting the ID back, just use:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

...after every `INSERT IGNORE` call you make.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something called an after-insert trigger on table B.  This is a piece of code that runs after inserting one or more rows into a table.  Documentation is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html).

The code is something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger AFTER INSERT ON B
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      -- Do what you want with each row here
  END;
```